# How will we convert latitude and longitude to the address in web site?

Tags: javascript, html, latitude-longitude

I have an API which gives latitude and longitude and i want the address of the place(city,area etc) based on the values.

Suppose the website like http://ip-api.com/php/2.50.153.139 if we give the ip of the location ,it will give the name of the location that we residing.
The json output will be like:

```
a:14:{s:5:"query";s:12:"2.50.153.139";s:10:"regionName";s:9:"Abu Dhabi";s:3:"lat";d:24.466699600219727;s:3:"org";s:39:"Emirates Telecommunications Corporation";s:3:"zip";s:0:"";s:2:"as";s:24:"AS5384 Emirates Internet";s:6:"status";s:7:"success";s:7:"country";s:20:"United Arab Emirates";s:4:"city";s:9:"Abu Dhabi";s:3:"lon";d:54.36669921875;s:8:"timezone";s:10:"Asia/Dubai";s:3:"isp";s:39:"Emirates Telecommunications Corporation";s:11:"countryCode";s:2:"AE";s:6:"region";s:2:"AZ";}
```

But in mu case i have latitude ,longitude and i want the area name.

I need it either by using php or by js .How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

include this script - 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>`

Then : -

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function GetAddress() {
            var lat = parseFloat(document.getElementById("#yourinputlat").value);
            var lng = parseFloat(document.getElementById("#yourinputlon").value);
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            var geocoder = geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    if (results[1]) {
                        alert("Location: " + results[1].formatted_address);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: @biswas May i know what is this results[1] ?

Comment: Actually the geocoder api gives closest address to the given lat and lon as you can see here :-
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=53,7

So results is the above output and results[1] is the second object of the output , if you want you can use also use results[0] and it will give you the first suggested result.

Answer (score 0):

Make ajax with below url and data -> lat and long

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=44.4647452,7.3553838&sensor=true

Answer (score 0):

You should try this one, and you're looking for Google's (or anyone else's) [reverse geocoding service.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start#ReverseGeocoding)